# Calling Matlab from VB

Tags: vb.net, matlab, visual-studio-2012

I am building an application in VB (VS2012) and the main code is written in Matlab. I would like to call the Matlab scripts from the VB form and also display the results of the calculations in the VB form in a datagrid. Can somebody suggest what my mode of exchange should be?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have Matlab compiler? If yes then you can create .net dlls files and can methods can be accessible in you VB program. You should read more about matlab compiler

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options.

1. MATLAB has a COM interface. From VB, you can start an instance of MATLAB, pass data to it, execute commands, retrieve results, and quit MATLAB. To find out more, take a look at the [documentation pages for the MATLAB COM Automation Server](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-matlab-com-automation-server.html). This method will require you to have a live copy of MATLAB present when you run your VB application.
2. You can use an add-on product to MATLAB, MATLAB Builder NE for .NET (you'll also require another add-on that it depends on, MATLAB Compiler). MATLAB Builder NE allows you to convert your MATLAB code into a standalone .NET assembly or COM component that can be called from your VB application, and distributed with it.

Note that contrary to a comment, MATLAB Compiler alone without MATLAB Builder NE does not allow you to produce .NET assemblies.